# how to increase lan speed to 1gbps

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have two computers both connected to router. Fist one is connected by cable and other is wireless connectivity. I have installed a software on first one and have shared the drive where software exe is present. I am able to access the software from the second machine. However it takes time to load data when I try to access some functionality from second computer. When I contacted the software provider, she mentioned that you would require lan speed upto 1gbps. If some one can guide me as I am not sure what all changes I need to do so as to achieve this speed.

Do I need to purchase a new router, or what else can I do?

Comment: this question is unanswerable with the data provided.  what make and model router do you have.

Comment: You can't get Gigabyte speeds from a wireless network.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your router supports 1000MBit on the LAN ports, then connect the other pc that is currently connected wirelessly to one of the ports on the router.

Make sure the cables are at least CAT5e, otherwise speeds of 1000MBit are not guaranteed.

In addition the network ports must require this as well, but chances are very high they are, because it has been a standard for many years now. Unless your pc is like 10 years old...

That said, I highly doubt that the software actually requires 1Gbit (or 1000Mbit) to work correctly. Its more likely that the person you spoke with doesn't understand what they're talking about because 1000Mbit is really fast, where wireless is usually really slow, like 30~50Mbit. I'm sure that if you simply connect that second pc using a cable, whether or not it actually gets 1000MBit, it will solve your problems.